# recordID has a value type of reference and cannot be queried

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

The error is: Field '__recordID' has a value type of reference and cannot be queried by using filter value type string.

Code:

```
func getImage() {
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID = %@", myRecordID)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Images", predicate: predicate)
publicDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil , completionHandler: ({ results, error in
    if(error != nil) {
            print("Error")
    }
    else {
    if results!.count > 0 {
        for record in results! {
            print("I have results from query")
        }
        else {
            print("query returned with no results")
        }
    }
}))
```

myRecordID is: 3F1CF4EC-95F4-4659-AA47-B00048B3BBAE which is valid

Comment: This works: publicDB.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: myRecordID), completionHandler: {record, error in. It seems performQuery will not work for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

Like the error is telling you: You have to query using a reference instead of a string.

So your code has to be:

```
let referenceField = "recordID"
let refId = CKRecordID(recordName: myRecordID)
let ref = CKReference(recordID: refId, action: CKReferenceAction.None)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", referenceField ,ref))
```

But then again. It's easier to get the record with something like:

```
publicDB.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: recordId), completionHandler: {record, error in
```